# How to create a podcast soundboard?

Tags: sound-effects

I have been fairly successful setting up my own DIY podcast from my home.  I use XLR mics, a 8-channel mixer, and record with Audacity.

The next step is adding additional sound elements to the podcast without having to fiddle around with lots of things on the computer.  I do have a computer feeding into the mix, but I mainly use this for searching the web, playing the intro/outro, playing songs, etc.

For sound effects, I'd much prefer to have a physical device that is pre-programmed with the sounds of my choice.  What are some of the best options for this?

Answer (score 2):

A solution that might work for you would be to use a combination of hardware controller with software to generate the sound effects.

The controller would look something like this:

[image]

Many people use [Ableton Live](http://www.ableton.com/live-8) for just what you are trying to do.  There are several hardware controllers that will work with it.  A few can be found [here](http://www.ableton.com/controllers).

I have never used this type of setup, so I don't have any specific product recommendations, but this should at least give you an idea of where to start looking.

Answer (score 2):

A "physical device that is pre-programmed with the sounds of my choice" is called a [sampler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampler_(musical_instrument)) and what kind you'll need is entirely up to your personal requirements. They can be [quite simple things](http://www.vintagesynth.com/roland/sp202.php) that basically just play back short recordings when you press a button, all the way up to [very elaborate devices](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/dec08/articles/akaimpc5000.htm) that you can [compose entire albums with](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entroducing). I personally have used the Boss SP-202 in the first link, and can say that while loading sounds onto it can be a bit awkward, it works quite well and simply once they're loaded.

However, to save cost, you may find that software works just as well for you, since you already have a computer running into your mixer. If you need physical buttons you can probably get a simple MIDI controller to trigger sounds with (a la [Friend of George's answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/3710/95)), although at that point you may as well go with a hardware sampler for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in what people will suggest as far hardware solutions, but you may save yourself some money and setup if you just insert the sound effects after the fact (post-production).

The basic process is to record your podcast as normal, and then in Audacity you can insert the sound effects or songs on a separate track and then mix down to a single file again. This is simply an alternative to your hardware solution - it may not fit in with the production process you had in mind.

Comment: This adds time + complexity, as well as removing elements from the live stream and the vibe of the show.  I definitely need the sounds in real time.

Thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

Soundboards have typically been dedicated PC's routed to the main mixer for years now, I was using one in 1997. If you are using a mixer in your podcast, you should have a look at SoundBoard for the iPad from Ambrosia Software for $20 and the price of an iPad (which you may already have) you can replicate the exact functionality of a radio station soundboard. I am not sure if there are Android equivalents but since the tablets don't have fans, run silently and are touch screen they are ideal for this purpose.

Comment: iPad is a good solution I guess, but do you think there is a solution that is a physical device?  The same concept, but with physical buttons.  A midi controller maybe?  I'm new to all audio related tech questions...

Comment: There are hardware versions but for a podcast, you are getting in some pretty pricey solutions.

Comment: What other software solutions are there for Windows machines?  Any suggestions?